# return (dispatch) do nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

i have a component which run this

```
 import { handleAddQuestion } from '../actions/questions';

 handleAddQuestion(optionOneText, optionTwoText, author)
```

in `actions/questions` i have

```
import { _saveQuestion } from '../utils/_DATA';
export function handleAddQuestion (optionOneText, optionTwoText, authedUser) {
  console.log("before")
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log("after")
    _saveQuestion({optionOneText, optionTwoText, author: authedUser}).then((question) => {
      let qid = question.id
      dispatch(saveUserQuestion(authedUser, qid))
      dispatch(addQuestion(question))
    })
  }

}
```

i get `before` in console but not `after` no action is triggered, nothing happens at all no matter what i change ,, it's like i cannot do this `return (dispatch)` !! i tried the same thing in another place which worked perfectlly, logged the data and triggered the actions ! what is wrong here !!!!!!!

more info `_DATA_.js`

```
export function _saveQuestion (question) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const authedUser = question.author;
    const formattedQuestion = formatQuestion(question);

    setTimeout(() => {
      questions = {
        ...questions,
        [formattedQuestion.id]: formattedQuestion
      }
      
      users = {
        ...users,
        [authedUser]: {
          ...users[authedUser],
          questions: users[authedUser].questions.concat([formattedQuestion.id])
        }
      }

      res(formattedQuestion)
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

`reducers/questions.js`

```
export function questions(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ADD_QUESTION:
        const { question } = action;
        return {
            ...state,
            [question.id]: question,
        };
    ///
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning what is called a `thunk` here - and thunks only get executed when actually being dispatched. Compare that with how it is called in the other places.

So correct would be calling

```
 dispatch(handleAddQuestion(optionOneText, optionTwoText, author))
```

Comment: That worked for me, rocky mistake, thanks :)

Comment: Adding to this: if you're just learning redux, you are following a very outdated tutorial - this is not the style of redux we're officially recommending to learn and it will lead to you writing lots of extra code. Look into the official redux tutorials over at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index ;)